# JqGrid sava row data to DB on click out of grid

Tags: jqgrid

I have a JQGrid with 3 columns. At the moment i hvae implementet it so that its a fully editable grid (where when you click on a row, its getting edittable). Right now to leave edit mode and save i have to press enter, but what i need is to have possibility to:

When i click out of grid in edit mode to autosave my selected row data to DB, but i still want to keep save on enter click button functionallity.

I dont know if it is possible to achieve so i have both functionallities on 1 grid.

here is the code for jqgrid

```
  var lastsel;
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
              url: '@Url.Action("SellerList")',
              datatype: 'json',
              mtype: 'GET',
              loadonce: true, // to enable sorting on client side
              sortable: true, //to enable sorting
              colNames: ['SellerKey', 'SellerId', 'Navn', 'Email', 'Slet'],
              colModel: [
                  { name: 'id ', index: 'id ', width: 50, key: true, editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: false }, hidden: true },
                  { name: 'SellerId', index: 'SellerId', align: 'center', width: 50, editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: false }, hidden: true },
                  { name: 'Navn', index: 'Navn', width: 200, edittype: 'text', align: 'left', editable: true, sortable: true },
                  { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', width: 300, edittype: 'text', align: 'left', editable: true, sortable: true },
                  { name: 'act', index: 'act', width: 80, align: 'center', sortable: false }],
              loadComplete: function() {
                  jQuery("#list").trigger("reloadGrid"); // Call to fix client-side sorting
              },
              gridComplete: function() {

                  var ids = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                  var gr = jQuery('#list'); gr.setGridHeight('auto', true);
                  for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                      var cl = ids[i];
                     var be = "<a href='#' value='Slet' onclick=\"jQuery('#list').jqGrid('delGridRow','" + cl + "',{reloadAfterSubmit:false, url:'@Url.Action("deleteRow")'}); return false;\">Slet </>";
                      jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], { act: be });
                  }
              },

              onSelectRow: function(id) {
                  if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                      jQuery('#list').jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel);
                      jQuery('#list').jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
                      lastsel = id;
                  }
              },


              editurl: '@Url.Action("GridSave")',
              rowNum: 100,
              rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
              viewrecords: true


          });
      var grid = jQuery("#list"); 
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', "#page", { edit: false, add: false, del: false }, { beforeShowForm: function(form) {
              // "editmodlist"
              var dlgDiv = grid.jqGrid("#delmodlist" + grid[0].id);
              var parentDiv = dlgDiv.parent(); // div#gbox_list
              var dlgWidth = dlgDiv.width();
              var parentWidth = parentDiv.width();
              var dlgHeight = dlgDiv.height();
              var parentHeight = parentDiv.height();
              // TODO: change parentWidth and parentHeight in case of the grid
              //       is larger as the browser window
              dlgDiv[0].style.top = Math.round((parentHeight-dlgHeight)/2) + "px";
              dlgDiv[0].style.left = Math.round((parentWidth-dlgWidth)/2) + "px";
          }});
  });
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to **save** the current editing row if the user clicks (select) another row?

Comment: yes, or if user click out of grid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save the current editing row if you click on another row of the grid you need just to use [saveRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#saverow) instead of [restoreRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#restorerow) inside of `onSelectRow` event handler:

```
onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
    if (rowid !== lastSel) {
        grid.jqGrid('saveRow', lastSel);
        lastSel = rowid;
    }
    grid.jqGrid('editRow', rowid, true);
    return true;
}
```

To save the row if you click somewhere **outside of the grid** I don't found any good solution. For example in IE9 the following code work good:

```
grid.focusout(function (e) {
    if (e.relatedTarget) {
        var $related = grid.find(e.relatedTarget);
        if ($related.length <= 0 && lastSel) {
            grid.jqGrid('saveRow', lastSel);
        }
    }
});
```

where `var grid = jQuery("#list");`
See the demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithInlineEditing3.htm). The same code not work in other web browsers. For IE8/IE7 `e.pageX` and `e.pageY` will be set in `focusout` (but not in IE9), so the properties can be used to calculate the mouse position and determine whether the position outside of the grid.

So I can't suggest you any good way to save the editing row on click *outside* of the grid.

Comment: it works, thanks again Oleg. sorry for slow response, didnt had time to test it, before now

Comment: Would something like this work when clicking outside of the grid?
 `var lastsel = "";
 $('body').bind('click', function(e) {
  if ( lastsel != "" ) { //if a row is selected for edit
      if($(e.target).closest('#commonDocumentsSearchResultsGrid').length == 0) { //and the click is outside of the grid
       //save the row being edited and unselect the row
       $searchResultsGrid.jqGrid('saveRow', lastsel);
       $searchResultsGrid.resetSelection();      
       lastsel=""; 
      }
  }
 });`

Comment: Hi @Oleg not sure if this needs a new question but I am using the `onSelectRow` part of this answer. I know this is a pretty old answer so wanted to check if this still works? I prepared a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HJema/197/) If I try to print the row, it does not have the updated data. The same happens if I try to save it. Is there any changes in the free-jqgrid code that might be causing this? or perhaps something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @DipenShah: I think that the answer is really old. I would better use `$(window).click` and test whether the clicked element is inside of the grid or not. You can use `jQuery.contains` for example. If you detect that the user clicked outside of the grid you can call `saveRow` to save the row.

Comment: Sorry @Oleg I think you misunderstood my question. What I want to do is if the user clicks on another row, the current row being edited should be saved. That's the part where I am supposed to use `onSelectRow` I think you are referring to the second part where if the user is clicking outside of the grid you save that row.

Comment: @DipenShah: You wrote "if the user clicks on **another row**, the **current row**". Do you mean that that you wan to save the date if the user click on **another column** on **the same row**? Moreover one can't use `getRowData` for the row which is in editing mode. You should *first* save the data and then can use `getRowData`.

Comment: Sorry I'll explain with an example. Let's say if I am currently editing the 2nd row, I make some changes in one of the cell and then I click on 3rd row without hitting the enter key, it should save the 2nd row. Also I tried `getRowData` after `saveRow` but it does not seem to have updated values.

Comment: @DipenShah: Sorry, but I can't reproduce what you say. I modified in your demo just one line. I moved `getRowData` after `saveRow` and it displays in console *modified* data: http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/HJema/198/. Of cause such works only with local data. If you would save the data to the server then one can use `getRowData` only inside of `aftersavefunc` (after the previous editing row will be really changed from editing mode to the standard display mode). I recommend better use `savedRow` parameter instead of `lastSel` variable.

Comment: Thank you @Oleg I think there is some other problem with my code because I don't see a `JSON` request going to my server in my real application. if I try to debug it. That means my `saveRow` is never being called. I will try some more and if I am not able to solve it, I will ask a new question as this kind of discussion is not constructive over an old answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @johndoe: I don't understand what you mean. There are above a discussion with some implementation options and the differences existing in web browsers (especially in old IE)

Comment: @Oleg Is it possible to save multiple rows in a single click i.e. I change values of say three cells and then click outside.Can I save all the rows in a click outside the grid?

Answer (score 2):

I found  icats' answer useful but it does not work in all situations as well.

I would suggest to bind to `$('html')` rather than to `$('body')`. Body may occupy not all visible space in your browser.